# Item Quantity Logic without Shopping Cart Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, e-commerce, inventory-management

I'm building a peer to peer marketplace and am trying to introduce item quantities for both buyers and sellers.  I do not have a shopping cart and users buy the product directly from the item page.

Right now the seller can choose the quantity of items they have for sale when they upload an item.  I have quantity as a column on the items table in the db.

My confusion comes when the buyer selects a quantity that they would like to purchase.  I thought I would just add another column to the items table like 'quantity_purchased' and when the buyer submits a quantity on the item page it would update this column, the price, etc.  I'm sure the problems with this are obvious if more than one buyer, or even interested party, exists.

I'm hoping someone here might be able to provide a different way to think about the solution without having to add a shopping cart.

Thank you for any help.  Every tutorial, SO question, etc assumes the existence of a shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

**My confusion comes when the buyer selects a quantity that they would like to purchase. I thought I would just add another column to the items table like 'quantity_purchased'**

As long as the functionality is correct, I don't see a problem here in your thinking.

There is the idea of having a "current state" application. So my thought would be that your 'quantity' column's count goes down as our user purchases items from your site, because that is no longer available for purchase. On the reverse end, the items_purchased column should go up incrementally upon a purchase. I am not incredibly fond of the naming there. Just for simplicities sake I would name it something like

quantity_for_sale

quantity_purchased

Then maybe lastly.....

quantity_total (for the total number of items that have come in and out.)

So if quanitty_for_sale = 60, and quantity_purchased = 40, then quantity_total = 100 .

The reason I suggest this, is so that would help to know your overhead. How much inventory you have vs how much you've sold. Might help recognize supply vs demand, and make intelligent business decisions. Hope that helps. There really is no right answer to database schema. Depends on your situation honestly, and we would probably need a little more info on the app as well, like what you are selling and what the other models and tables look like, so on and so forth.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I was thinking along these lines but I wouldn't want the quantity_purchased  column to be updated until the payment was successful.  Which means perhaps I need four columns in total, quantity_for_sale, quantity_requested, quantity_purchased, and quantity_total.  That way the quantity_requested could be tied to the user_id and not affect inventory if it's abandoned or changed by multiple users.